# How can I display Touch Bar Buttons using SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm trying to add Touch Bar support for a `SwiftUI` `View`. There seems to be `SwiftUI` API for this using the `.touchBar(content: () -> View)` function on Views, but documentation is non existent and I can't get my Touch Bar to display anything.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .touchBar {
                Button(action: {

                }) {
                    Text("do something")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This code does compile and run, but the Touch Bar remains empty. How can I get my touch bar to display content using SwiftUI (not catalyst)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `.focusable` doesn't work without "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls" checked in `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts`. To work around that, I did this:

```
/// Bit of a hack to enable touch bar support.
class FocusNSView: NSView {
    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

/// Gets the keyboard focus if nothing else is focused.
struct FocusView: NSViewRepresentable {

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<FocusView>) -> FocusNSView {
        return FocusNSView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: FocusNSView, context: Context) {

        // Delay making the view the first responder to avoid SwiftUI errors.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            if let window = nsView.window {

                // Only set the focus if nothing else is focused.
                if let _ = window.firstResponder as? NSWindow {
                    window.makeFirstResponder(nsView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works amazing! Just to add, you have to use FocusNSView() inside your View where touchBar modifier is used. I also use frame(width: 0, height: 0) on the FocusNSView! Thank you!!

Comment: I would be so happy if we would not need this kind of workarounds as of WWDC 2020

Answer (score 3):

Help from this [How to use a SwiftUI touchbar with a NSWindow - Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/127071#thread-post-401151):

> Use the focusable() modifier

The touch bar shows the text when you add the `.focusable()` modifier just before the `.touchBar(content:)` modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .focusable()
            .touchBar {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Perform some action")
                }) {
                    Text("do something")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Touch bar image]

Comment: Thank you for helping. I ran this code, but the Touch Bar remains empty. Did this code work for you?

Comment: @Vincent It did, appeared just on the left next to `esc`. I added an image to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Apparently there was one more thing I needed to do to make it work. I needed to open `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` and make sure 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls' is checked. Seems like a SwiftUI bug (or at least very unexpected behaviour) :)

Comment: @Vincent Is there any workaround for that? The user won't have that activate maybe..

Comment: I haven't found any workaround. I hope this get smoothened out in the next release of swiftUI